# Is it possible to load multiple ontologies with Jena?

Tags: sparql, jena, ontology

I am new with Jena and I am implementing an application in order to manipulate RDF data. I have already implemented some basic fonctions to see Classes, Properties and other stuffs.

And I wonder if it could be possible to load multiple ontologies with Jena and then have some SPARQL queries on those. (I already know that is possible because Protégé does it).

Thank's for your interest.
I'm open for any questions or precision.

Comment: Couldn't you just import the second ontology into the model?

Comment: "possible to load multiple ontologies with Jena and then have some SPARQL queries on those."  You can read multiple RDF documents into the same Model (or OntModel) and run SPARQL queries on that.  What did you try and what didn't work about it?  It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: @Joshua Thank's you I didn't undersand that I could load mutltiple ontology in the same Model. I am going to explore this way.